# Assign a role to a client secret in a private application

Tags: .net, azure, authentication, oauth-2.0, azure-ad-msal

In a on premises application we are attempting to access an API which we have hosted within azure as a private application. We assign roles to our users though AAD and the roles are defined in the application manifest

```
"appRoles": [    
...
    {
        "allowedMemberTypes": [
            "User",
            "Application"
        ],
        "description": "Read Only All",
        "displayName": "Read Only All",
        "id": "***",
        "isEnabled": true,
        "lang": null,
        "origin": "Application",
        "value": "ReadOnlyAll"
    }
],
```

We have created the client secret and while we can connect to a public application following the documentation on on [MSAL client credential flows](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/wiki/Client-credential-flows) but doing this we lose the ability to assign roles. Additionally I can connect to the private application following [Authenticating to Azure AD in daemon apps with certificates](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-daemon-certificate-credential#authenticating-to-azure-ad-in-daemon-apps-with-certificates) but we get an error stating that the client application does not have a role assigned to the service application. so at this point we are at a loss of how to get a token from Azure with a role assigned to the client application.

There is no direct way (as far as we can tell) to assign a client application a role to a private application whether through the certificates and secrets, API Permissions or authorized client applications.

So to summarize, my question is whether it is possible to assign a role to an on premises client application which reads from a service application hosted on Azure.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You are unable to add the app permission? Is the option to add a required app permission grayed out?

Comment: @juunas Sorry, you'll have to be a little more specific, I don't know what section you're referring to. in Enterprise application > Users and Groups there is no way to assign a role to a client secret. API Permissions under Azure Ad > app registration does not provide a way to assign a role to a delegated application and application permissions is not available

Comment: Sounds like your app is registered as a public client? What kind of app is your on-prem app?

Comment: @juunas The application is registered as a private client, and the on-prem application is a .Net application deployed to IIS. do you know if it is possible to assign a role to an application that uses a client secret known to a private application? does one give reference to and assign the role to an app through Azure Ad > app registration > my APIs > application permissions?

Comment: Yeah, app permissions are called app roles under the hood. That's where you are supposed to do the assignment.

Comment: @juunas I see. that clears some things up but I don't seem to be able to select it as my api permissions option. I have some azure apps which are registered that I can play around with, but with playing around with the various combinations of public and private clients did not find a way to assign an application with application permissions; only delegate. what state would an application need to be in to do this?

Comment: Interestingly of my app pool there are 2 or 3 of the numerous apps which can be assigned the Read All role under application permissions but I can't seem to find what the difference is between them which allows/disallows this

Comment: Hi @AdamM. So basically , you registered an Azure AD application for your on-prem application so that you can access Azure related resources using this application , and you want to  know how to assign a Role of other apps to it  in Enterprise application?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to assign an enterprise app role to an application that you registered in "App registrations" , AFAK , we can not do that on Azure portal , but we can finish this process by Azure AD Powershell , try the command below :

```
Connect-AzureAD 

$appObjId = "object id of the app that you want to assign role to"
$roleOwnerAppObjId = "object id of the role owner app" 

$sp = Get-AzureADServicePrincipal -ObjectId $roleOwnerAppObjId

$role= $sp.AppRoles | Where-Object { $_.DisplayName -eq "Read Only All" }

New-AzureADServiceAppRoleAssignment -ObjectId $appObjId -PrincipalId $appObjId -ResourceId $sp.ObjectId -Id $role.Id
```

You can find object IDs here :
[image]

Once I assigned the role , as you can see, role claim will be added when I request an access token to access resources of role owner app:
[image]

[image]

If there is anything unclear or misunderstand , pls feel free to let me know .

Comment: Hi @AdamM , is it helpful for you ?

Comment: While it may have been helpful, I used the comments from @junnas to help me get the correct authentication flow.

Answer (score 0):

So To fix this for myself I used the comments from @junnas to help me get the authentication flow working for my applications.

I have registered private applications for the on prem application deployments and assigned the applications application permissions (a role) in Azure Ad > app registration > my APIs > application permissions
this required having the role in the azure application having

```
"allowedMemberTypes": [
            "User",
            "Application" 
        ],
```

and the registered applications for the on prem application deployments be private.

With the role assigned to the application I could format my authentication flow following the documentation on  [v2 oauth 2.0 client credential grant flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow). essentially using the on prem registered application with a client secret and the new scope to get the required authentication (bearer token) to connect to, with a role, the private azure application using the MSALAuthenticator library

```
public MSALAuthenticator()
{
    _onPremClientId = "***";
    _tenantId = "***";
    _authorityFormat = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{0}/v2.0";
    _onPremClientSecret = "***";
    _scope = _onPremClientId + "/.default";

    _confAuthClient = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create(_onPremClientId)
        .WithAuthority(string.Format(_authorityFormat, _tenantId))
        .WithClientSecret(_onPremClientSecret)
        .Build();

   authResult = await _confAuthClient.AcquireTokenForClient(new[] { _scope }).ExecuteAsync();

    //this will be the authentication information, including bearer token for authentication headers to uses in api requests
    return authResult;
}
```